# How to remove all except alphanumeric characters from string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to remove all special characters from the following string:

```
abc // t?% ?? ttt ,. y  Ä Ö Ü ä, ö !
```

With regex:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
```

But this regex also remove `Ä Ö Ü ä, ö` but I want to keep those characters.
I want to remove only characters like: `!@#$%^&,;:'....`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `\p{L}` into the negated character class instead of `a-z`, `A-Z` . `\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language. By adding this to a negated character class would match any character but not of letters.

```
@"[^\p{L}0-9 -]"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pR3mK3/1)

```
string str = "abc // t?% ?? ttt ,. y  Ä Ö Ü ä, ö !";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\p{L}0-9 -]", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
abc  t  ttt  y  Ä Ö Ü ä ö
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ZML5W0)

Comment: Arguably on the same basis as using Unicode catgeory `L for all letters you should also use `N` for all numbers: `[^\p{L}\p{N} -]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Func<char, bool> filter = ch => char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) ||
                                char.IsWhiteSpace(ch) ||
                                ch == '-';

var abc = new string(str.Where(filter).ToArray());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MBRsPX

Comment: update: this removes space and '-'  your sample at dotnetfiddle removes space, '-' and the digits

Comment: + i like that delegate approach